# popout an image when clicked similar to tumblr

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a website, and am having difficulty knowing how to popout/expand a selection similar to these examples:

http://www.tumblr.com/

http://www.mistwalkercorp.com/album/album/gallery1.html

Would I need to use JS? PHP? Both? Just plain html? And how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "popouts" are called "lightbox". They are available as a plugin for various libraries like jQuery and mootools. The example website (http://www.mistwalkercorp.com/album/album/gallery1.html) uses "bind zoom" based on slimbox http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox

few others:
colorbox,
fancybox

a good list here as well
http://www.macnative.com/top-10-best-jquery-lightbox-clones/

Comment: Wow! That is quite the surprise. For some reason I thought it was some homegrown function that these groups made.

Comment: Yes.. Plugins make life lot easier.. thanks to people who take the time to develop these wonderful solutions for us to use.

Answer (score 1):

These are usually called lightboxes, and they're done with JavaScript. There are dozens of popular pre-existing JavaScript libraries to do it. One of my favorites is [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference friend, I'll check it out.